# How to exclude or hide the subfolder name in the URL when you open a webpage using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I have a website that has an example URL like localhost/projects/mysite/app/index.php, my objective is to exclude the folder name "app" when I open it, and instead, it shows only localhost/projects/mysite/index.php. What is the best way to exclude or hide the sub-folders and show directly the webpage in the address bar/URL?

I tried to remove `.php` in the URL and it succeed. However, I can't find a way to exclude the folder name. Also, here are the steps I have done so far:

[image]

Comment: Assuming you're attempting this with an .htaccess file, so can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to try to emulate the structure you want when it goes live so you don't need to have completely different settings locally and in prod? Then you would just need set the web servers document root to be the folder your index.php is in and access it with just `localhost`.

Comment: “ I tried to remove .php in the URL and it succeed.” - how did you do this?

Comment: I have tried to use RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] to hide the .php and tried this RewriteRule ^app/(.*) mysite/app/$1 [R=301,NC,L] to hide the subfolder name but it didn't worked.

Comment: Depends on the URL. Is the `app` always going to be the last directory that you want to exclude ?